# Is it possible to retrieve the latest uploaded asset rendition in AEM?

Tags: java, aem

For my video assets, I want to set my own thumbnails by adding a new rendition on assets. I am able to retrieve all the renditions uploaded using the getRenditions method however, I want to retrieve the path for the latest uploaded rendition only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to iterate Asset's Renditions and find the latest one, looking at "jcr:lastModified" property, here is untested code sample:

```
          Rendition lastRendition = null;
          Date lastDate = null;
          for (Rendition r : asset.getRenditions()) {
              Date date = r.getProperties().get(JcrConstants.JCR_LASTMODIFIED);
              if (lastDate == null || date.after(lastDate)) {
                 lastRendition = r;
                 lastDate = date;
              }
          }
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea! I was able to do this but with rendition.getResourceMetadata().getCreationTime();